# Dojo datagrid won't display inside another div

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid

I'm trying to get a Dojo datagrid working - I have replicated the first example on the documentation page (http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/grid/DataGrid) & it works just fine.

However, when I try to display the grid inside another div (i.e. putting 'gridContainer4' from the example inside any other div) nothing displays...

Any help would be much appreciated - can't find anything about this anywhere online!

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out:

The example text creates the new dojox.grid.DataGrid and applies it to  "document.createElement('div')" - changing this to the ID of an existing div fixed the problem (rather than appendChild-ing it to another div)

Original code:

`var grid4 = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
query: {
   Title: '*'
},
store: store4,
clientSort: true,
rowSelector: '20px',
structure: layout4
},  document.createElement('div'));`

changes to:

`var grid4 = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
query: {
   Title: '*'
},
store: store4,
clientSort: true,
rowSelector: '20px',
structure: layout4
}, "gridContainer4");`